# HTML + CSS - Resize images for mobile only

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I'll just jump straight in and show you rather than explain.

So this is how my website looks on browser:
[image]

And this is how my website looks when it's viewed on mobile:
[image]

Anyone give me any advice on how to fix it? I've tried bootstrap and media queries but im struggling with getting something to resize the images to a small enough size so that they appear next to each other on mobile.

Head:

```css
img.mob-img {
  width: 220;
  height: 333;
}   
  @media screen and (max-width: 992) {
    img.mob-img {
      width: 100px;
      height: auto;
    }       
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600) {
    img.mob-img {
      width: 100px;
      height: auto;
    }       
  }
```

```html
<head>
  <title>DrinkMania - Drink or Dare</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
  <meta name="description" content="Drink or Dare! - Truth or dare developed with students in mind!">
  <meta name="keywords" content="kings, ring of fire, drinking games, drinkmania, drinking games online,student, frat, dirty pint, kings cup, drinking games online,
  app, mobile website, android, ios, reddit, scott montford, playing cards, university, party, friends, talisman webs">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-145322216-2"></script>
  <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', '');
  </script>
</head>
<body class="is-preload">

Section of the body:

  <!-- Banner -->
  <section id="banner" data-video="images/banner">
    <div class="inner">
      <header>
        <h1>Drink or Dare</h1><br>
        <p id="kingCount"></p><br>
        <img id="drinks" class="mob-img" src="assets/js/games/Cards/card-placeholder.png" > OR
        <img id="wildcard" class="mob-img" src="assets/js/games/Cards/card-placeholder.png" >
      </header>
      <ul class="actions special">
        <li><a href="#" class="button primary large" onclick="drawCard()">Draw 2 Cards</a></li><br>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#one" class="more">Learn More</a>
    <video src="images/banner.mp4" muted autoplay loop playsinline></video>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: 1st advice would be to share your html and css code...

Comment: Please share your code so we can work with it.

Comment: Easy answer would be to give your images 100% width. Ideally only on mobile by a media query <992px or <768px. If your images do not have similar dimensions, you'll have to set max-height to align them properly.

Comment: Added my code. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I set the image into a container `<div style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">` and add max-width to your image css

```css
img.mob-img {
  width: 220px;
  height: 333px;
}   
@media screen and (max-width: 992) {
  img.mob-img {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
  }       
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600) {
  img.mob-img {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
  }       
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>DrinkMania - Drink or Dare</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
  <meta name="description" content="Drink or Dare! - Truth or dare developed with students in mind!">
  <meta name="keywords" content="kings, ring of fire, drinking games, drinkmania, drinking games online,student, frat, dirty pint, kings cup, drinking games online,
  app, mobile website, android, ios, reddit, scott montford, playing cards, university, party, friends, talisman webs">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-145322216-2"></script>
  <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', '');
  </script>
</head>

<body class="is-preload">

Section of the body:

  <!-- Banner -->
  <section id="banner" data-video="images/banner">
    <div class="inner">
      <header>
        <h1>Drink or Dare</h1><br>
        <p id="kingCount"></p><br>
        <div style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">
          <img id="drinks" class="mob-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/31/07/10/billboards-4807268_960_720.jpg" > OR
          <img id="wildcard" class="mob-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/06/20/25/dog-3204497_960_720.jpg" >
        </div>
      </header>
      <ul class="actions special">
        <li><a href="#" class="button primary large" onclick="drawCard()">Draw 2 Cards</a></li><br>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#one" class="more">Learn More</a>
    <video src="images/banner.mp4" muted autoplay loop playsinline></video>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, you don't need to set two different max-widths when the values you're putting in them are the same. I would put the width at 100% with a max-width of 100px if that's the size you need. I'm not a big fan of inline css like you have it. I would rename the div you have the flex applied to and then put the code in with your other styling so it's not all over the place. It just helps to see it in one spot if you can.

```
   <div id="cards">
          <img id="drinks" class="mob-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/31/07/10/billboards-4807268_960_720.jpg" > OR
          <img id="wildcard" class="mob-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/06/20/25/dog-3204497_960_720.jpg" >
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#cards {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}

img.mob-img {
  width: 220px;
  height: 333px;
}   
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  img.mob-img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
  }       
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are trying to do? I made sure it is responsive too. I didn't need to use any of the CSS you provided since you said you are using bootstrap.

I also made a few changes to the HTML by adding more `div`s to get this result.

if this is not your desired output please let me know in a comment I will try my best to help you out.

Ps. I commented out the video because it was causing horizontal scrolling.

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-holder {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section id="banner" data-video="images/banner">
  <div class="inner">
    <header>
      <h1>Drink or Dare</h1><br>
      <p id="kingCount"></p><br>
      <div class="holder">
        <div class="image-container">
          <div class="image-holder">
            <img id="drinks" class="mob-img img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
          </div>
          <span>OR</span>
          <div class="image-holder">
            <img id="drinks" class="mob-img img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/201">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <ul class="actions special">
      <li><a href="#" class="button primary large" onclick="drawCard()">Draw 2 Cards</a></li><br>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#one" class="more">Learn More</a>
  <!-- <video src="images/banner.mp4" muted autoplay loop playsinline></video> -->
</section>


<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```